# Capistrano deploy fails for repo that was moved from github to private git.. stil trying to contact github.. why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano

I have a Rails 4 project that started at github and then it was moved to a private git repository. I can work perfectly with the repo (push, clone). I searched for references to the github repo somewhere in the code but none exists.. it must be something related to GIT and how the repository started..

**Important:** I was able to deploy with this configuration from my private repo until I removed the github one.

Of course I have updated config/deploy.rb

```
set :repo_url, '/srv/git/project.git'
```

Running "git remote -v":

```
origin  git@git.server:/srv/git/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.server:/srv/git/project.git (push)
```

Log of capistrano run "bundle exec cap production deploy":

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
server's password:
    ✔ 01 server 6.019s
00:07 git:check
      01 git ls-remote --heads /srv/git/project.git
      01 6b0c9f5ad2d8e768902c5da1509fd99915068295       refs/heads/master
    ✔ 01 server 0.356s
00:07 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /home/user/applications/project/shared /home/user/applications/project/releases
    ✔ 01 user@server 0.335s
00:08 deploy:check:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /home/user/applications/project/shared/public/assets
    ✔ 01 user@server 0.331s
00:09 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /home/user/applications/project/repo
00:10 git:update
      01 git remote update --prune
      01 Fetching origin
      01 remote: Invalid username or password.
      01 fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user/project.git/'
      01 error: Could not fetch origin
```

Moved from SVN to GIT not so much ago and a bit confused about this behaviour.. any help apreciated!

Comment: How to get such a short and user-friendly capistrano log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the origin on the server. The easiest way to accomplish this would probably be to SSH into the server, navigate to `/home/user/applications/project/repo` and:

```
git remote set-url origin /srv/git/project.git
```

I don't believe that capistrano will automatically update the remote.

Comment: It was just that.. I didn't know that Capistrano keeped a clone of the repository there: I belived it cloned it from scratch at each reploy from the repo in the url.. Thanks

Comment: Downloading the whole repository on each deploy would take a lot of time, compared to just the delta.